# Built-in strongly-typed validator in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-validation

Currently my models implement `IValidatableObject` what means they aren't lean POCO's as I'd like them to be.

If I'm using `ValidationAttribute` then I have to deal with `object`.

If I'm using `ActionFilterAttribute` then I have to deal with `context.ActionArguments` collection.

IS there a built-in strongly-typed validator which can be injected globally and will be triggered only for given `T`? Like [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration) but out-of--the-box?